# Reactjs app's production build Javascript gets disabled, <noscript> tag in <body>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a Reactjs with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

I installed it with npm and create an app using `create-react-app myapp`

Everything works fine for development with `yarn start`

But when I build the production build with `yarn build` deploy and run with

`yarn global add serve` & `serve -s build` app runs as java script disabled with

```
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
```

in the body. I did a bit of a research on this and found out that we need to deploy the production build with SSL enabled so I created self-signed certificated and configured Apache on a Cloud VM and deployed the app. But unfortunately, the result is same.

Can someone kindly provide directions to solve this issue? I need to confirm the production setup before going into further development. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake by saying that javascript is not working, since its was working well. As to my knowledge `<noscript>` tag should only appear if javascript is truly disabled thus I concluded it is the case while in fact javascript was working fine. I apologize for my lack of knowledge on the subject. Anyway may this question be a help to someone like me.